# An error occurred while quiescing the virtual machine

Tags: backup, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server, vss, acronis

I got an backup issue on one of my VM.
Here is the current situation:

1. Using Acronis backup to backup my VM

   > vmProtect 9
2. Server I want to get backup is

   > Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition Service Pack2
3. Using vSphere client to manage my VMs

   > vSphere Client Version 5.1.0
4. When backup ran, it failed with error an message under **"Create virtual machine snapshot"** stage.

   > "An error occurred while quiescing the virtual machine. See the virtual machine's event log for details."
5. Tried following:

   - Rebooted the server -> issue still exist
   - Install/Upgraded VMware tools

     > Installed and updated by using:
     >   vSphere -> right click server -> Guest -> Install/Upgrade VMware Tools
     >   But issue still exist
   - Uninstalled and re-installed VMware tools

     > Rebooted the box after the re-installation but still getting same error message.
   - Checked "vssadmin list writers" on the actual virtual machine

     > all VSS writers are:
     >   State: [1] Stable
     >   Last error: No error
   - **Checked Event log (Event Viewer) on the actual virtual machine**

     > In Application log, warning message found as following:
     >   a) [ warning] [vmvss:vmvss] CVmSnapshotRequestor::WaitForOperation():2563: Async operation result: Operation aborted
     >   
     >   Information message found as following:
     >   a) The Volume Shadow Copy service was successfully sent a start control.
     >   b) The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the running state.
   - Confirmed I can create snapshot without "Quiesce guest file system" option, but Acronis backup need this option to be on.
6. Due to Creating snapshot fails with "Quiesce guest file system" option on in vSphere, I believe that backup is failing at VM level and not at Acronis level

Thank you for reading this and any help or advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `An error occurred while quiescing the virtual machine. See the virtual machine's event log for details.` ... aaaaand, those details from the virtual machine's event log would be, what, exactly?

Comment: From the event viewer, there weren't any error log under System and Applications which related to the backup issue. Also vSphere's event only shows Task: Create virtual machine snapshot, but no error message found.

Comment: Only Information message found which stated "The Volume Shadow Copy service was successfully sent a start control." and "The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the running state."

Comment: Does the server have VMtools installed on it?

Comment: Yes, by using vSphere -> right click server -> Guest -> Install/Upgrade VMware Tools

Comment: In Application log, warning message found as following:
[ warning] [vmvss:vmvss] CVmSnapshotRequestor::WaitForOperation():2563: Async operation result: Operation aborted

Comment: few options:
1: disable the anti virus
2: try this kb http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2009065
3: upgrade to 5.5 or later

Comment: consolidate the vm and migrate to other datastore.
and try to take snapshot with quiesce option

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of errors that may be raised when working with snapshots, some of them are general (not related to a specific guest OS) and some are related to MS Windows family of OSs. Most of the times, generic problems are fixed by just consolidating the VM or removing all snapshots. Switching the guest OS off and consolidating and/or removing snapshots suffices most of the times. We have written a complete guide on what to do in this cases: 
https://33hops.com/esxi-snapshot-errors-and-solutions.html

There is a well known bug that affects Microsoft's OS and renders the exact symptoms you are describing. It's not clear whose fault it is VMWare/ Microsoft, as they blame each other and the problem has not been solved so far, and probably will never be solved. Details here: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006849

The good news is that this bug/ problem, only affects MBR based installations, thus if you use a GPT boot disk, snapshotting and quiescing will work flawlessly. The thing is, what do you do if your OS is MBR based and you can't reinstall everything. You have two options:

1 - Renounce to quiesce the OS, which might not be an option, if you are running database or e-mail servers per instance.

2 - Convert your MBR partition to a GPT one without data loss. There are a number of tools out there, but this is a free solution and has worked for us so far http://sabrnet.wzk.cz/2015/03/convert-windows-system-mbr-disk-to-gpt-with-efi-without-data-loss/